# mysql won't run from command line

Tags: mysql, command

When trying to run the /etc/bin/mysql command from the command line, I'm returned to the prompt without any action.

Restarting mysql via /etc/init.d/mysql restart shows the following error during the check routine and the script hangs (although mysql starts ok).

```
root@webshared001:/usr/bin# /etc/init.d/mysql restart

* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld
   ...done.

* Starting MySQL database server mysqld
   ...done.

* Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables.

root@webshared001:/usr/bin# /usr/share/mysql/debian-start.inc.sh: line 69: [: : integer expression expected
---
```

Restarting the machine doesn't help

```
MySql is currently running an processing queries with no problems.
System is Xubuntu
```

Comment: What does `/usr/share/mysql/debian-start.inc.sh` say, especially near line 69?

Answer (score 0):

Line 69 is the last if statement and checks mySQL for blank root passwords.  I'm not sure what the $MYSQL --skip-column-names is and may not be an integer.

I've run the select statement that is assigned to the ret variable and it returns 0.

I also scanned the .cnf files for any reference to --skip-column-names and couldn't find anything.

Here's /usr/share/mysql/debian-start.inc.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #
 # This file is included by /etc/mysql/debian-start
 #

 ## Check all unclosed tables.
 # - Requires the server to be up.
 # - Is supposed to run silently in background.
 function check_for_crashed_tables() {
   set -e
   set -u

   # But do it in the background to not stall the boot process.
   logger -p daemon.info -i -t$0 "Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables"

   # Checking for $? is unreliable so the size of the output is checked.
   # Some table handlers like HEAP do not support CHECK TABLE.
   tempfile=`tempfile`
   # We have to use xargs in this case, because a for loop barfs on the
   # spaces in the thing to be looped over.
   LC_ALL=C $MYSQL --skip-column-names --batch -e  '
       select concat('\''select count(*) into @discard from `'\'',
                     TABLE_SCHEMA, '\''`.`'\'', TABLE_NAME, '\''`'\'')
       from information_schema.TABLES where ENGINE='\''MyISAM'\' | \
     xargs -i $MYSQL --skip-column-names --silent --batch \
                     --force -e "{}" >$tempfile
   if [ -s $tempfile ]; then
     (
       /bin/echo -e "\n" \
         "Improperly closed tables are also reported if clients are accessing\n" \
              "the tables *now*. A list of current connections is below.\n";
             $MYADMIN processlist status
          ) >> $tempfile
          # Check for presence as a dependency on mailx would require an MTA.
          if [ -x /usr/bin/mailx ]; then
            mailx -e -s"$MYCHECK_SUBJECT" $MYCHECK_RCPT < $tempfile
          fi
          (echo "$MYCHECK_SUBJECT"; cat $tempfile) | logger -p daemon.warn -i -t$0
        fi
        rm $tempfile
      }

      ## Check for tables needing an upgrade.
      # - Requires the server to be up.
      # - Is supposed to run silently in background.
      function upgrade_system_tables_if_necessary() {
        set -e
        set -u

   logger -p daemon.info -i -t$0 "Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary."

   # Filter all "duplicate column", "duplicate key" and "unknown column"
   # errors as the script is designed to be idempotent.
   LC_ALL=C $MYUPGRADE \
     2>&1 \
     | egrep -v '^(1|@had|ERROR (1054|1060|1061))' \
     | logger -p daemon.warn -i -t$0
 }

 ## Check for the presence of both, root accounts with and without password.
 # This might have been caused by a bug related to mysql_install_db (#418672).
 function check_root_accounts() {
   set -e
   set -u

   logger -p daemon.info -i -t$0 "Checking for insecure root accounts."

   ret=$( echo "SELECT count(*) FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root' and password='';" | $MYSQL --skip-column-names )
    if [ "$ret" -ne "0" ]; then # THIS IS LINE 69
     logger -p daemon.warn -i -t$0 "WARNING: mysql.user contains $ret root accounts without password!"
   fi
 }
```